# Which directory does Ruby store its libraries in? (Windows 7)

Tags: ruby, windows-7

When I search for this on google most of what comes up is the difference between `load`, `require`, etc. The closest I found [was a tutorial that said](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/digging-into-a-ruby-installation-require-vs-load/) the libraries are held within `rubylibdir` but this directory does not appear to be on my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `gem env` in your command line and then look for `GEM PATHS` – this is where all of your gems are. For example, on my machine:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  ...
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
     - /Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
  ...
```